# Is there a Java version to c#'s CIM_VideoControllerResolution class?

Tags: java, version

[Link to said class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Or a class in general that lists all possible modes that is not DisplayManager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want exactly, but how about [GraphicsDevice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) or [DisplayMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/DisplayMode.html)?

GraphicsDevice is obtainable by:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

Then you can get DisplayMode by:

```
DisplayMode displayMode = gs[0].getDisplayMode();
```

You can obtain resolution information by `displayMode.getHeight()` and `displayMode.getWidth()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using Android Studio and it says it cannot resolve these symbols.Looks like they belong to the java.awt package which cannot be imported to AS. I've tried with DisplayMode, more specifically DisplayManager.getDisplays() but I only got one Display which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Stormtrooper does your Android device have more than one display?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to talk about the Display.Modes  which is the endgame for me, though yes from what I understand the TV I'm working on does have 2 "displays" - it's usual one and the HDMI one it gets from the set-top box.